# Issue when trying to pass array value as string via props in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="piza in pizas" :key="piza.pname">
      {{ piza.pname }}
      <List :content="matchpizza" :pname="pizas.pname" :qname="quantitys.qname" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import List from "./List.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    List,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pizas: [
        {
          pname: "chicken pizza",
        },
        {
          pname: "chicken pizza spl",
        },
        {
          pname: "mutton pizza",
        },
        {
          pname: "plain pizza",
        },
      ],

      quantitys: [
        {
          qname: "one",
        },
        {
          qname: "*two",
        },
        {
          qname: "*three",
        },
        {
          qname: "*four",
        },
        {
          qname: "*five",
        },
      ],

      matchpizza: [
        {
          matchnum: "1",
          availability: "later",
          pname: "drone piza",
          qname: "nine",
        },
        {
          matchnum: "2",
          availability: "buy now",
          pname: "chicken pizza",
          qname: "one",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="matchpizza.length > 0">
      <div
        v-for="match in matchpizza"
        :key="match.matchnum"
        :class="{
          green: match.availability === 'buy now',
          red: match.availability === 'later',
        }"
      >
        <div v-for="quantity in quantitys" :key="quantity.qname">
          {{ quantity.qname }}
        </div>
        <div class="next-data-two">{{ match.availability }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="next-data"><p>No availability</p></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: {
    content: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    pname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    qname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data: function () {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    quantitys() {
      return this.content.filter((a) => a.qname === this.qname);
    },
    matchpizza() {
      return this.content.filter((a) => a.pname === this.pname);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.next-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-top: -2%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  color: blue;
}
.next-data-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-right: 42%;
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
</style>
```

Issue when trying to filter the **matchpizza array for **pname** and **qname** array value.

Same array values 'pname and qname' having in **pizzas and quantitys** array.

condition is like:- if in matchpizza array, if i have same array value 'pname and qname' which has already exists in the **pizzas and quantitys**  array, then i need to show the value. or else condition.

Not sure , what i have written is correct logic for that?

Errors:-

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "pname". Expected String, got Undefined

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "qname". Expected String, got Undefined

code (errors in console) :- https://codesandbox.io/s/data-display-tcr8oj?file=/src/components/List.vue

Comment: It looks like you never defined the variable `quantity` so it is undefined. To made it to work, you should change your loop to use the index (`v-for="(piza, index) in pizas"`)and then: `quantitys[index].qname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not accessing the values **by index** or the **correct loop item**.

Here is the fixed version of your `HelloWorld.vue` file.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(piza, index) in pizas" :key="piza.pname">
      {{ piza.pname }}
      <List
        :content="matchpizza"
        :pname="piza.pname"
        :qname="quantitys[index] ? quantitys[index].qname : ''"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried the logic provided, But it is giving wrong path result, According to my output from codesandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/data-display-tcr8oj?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

For chicken pizza it showing as , chicken pizza --> one --> later...  But correct path is, chicken pizza --> later --> five... similarly for others also showing wrong path

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped the passing data and quantities is array you need to loop over it. Look at your props it should be `pizas.pname` and `quantitys[index].qname` you are missing the trailing 's'

**List component**

```
<List :content="matchpizza" :pname="pizas.pname" :qname="quantity.qname" />
```

**Object**

```
  pizas: [
        {
          pname: "chicken pizza",
        },
        {
          pname: "chicken pizza spl",
        },
        {
          pname: "mutton pizza",
        },
        {
          pname: "plain pizza",
        },
      ],
    
      quantitys: [
        {
          qname: "one",
        },
        {
          qname: "*two",
        },
        {
          qname: "*three",
        },
        {
          qname: "*four",
        },
        {
          qname: "*five",
        },
      ],
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You're accessing an undefined variable in **quantitys.qname** and you mistyped **piza.name** with **pizas.name**.

**Solution 1**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(piza, index) in pizas" :key="index"> <!--- Add Index, and replace piza.name with index just in case the same name might happen later
      {{ piza.pname }}
      <List
        :content="matchpizza"
        :pname="piza.pname" <!-- change pizas.name to piza.name
        :qname="quantitys[index] ? quantitys[index].qname : ''" <!-- add this
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

You can use **piza.pname** because you've looped through **pizas** in the div tag. You use **index** (starts from 0) after declaring it along with **piza**. Then, you can access quantitys value based on the working index and the index will be the same as the index you're accessing the **pizas**.

**Solution 2**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(piza, index) in pizas" :key="index"> 
      {{ piza.pname }}
      <List
        :content="matchpizza"
        :pname="pizas[index].pname" <--- Use index to access the values of pizas
        :qname="quantitys[index] ? quantitys[index].qname : ''"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is just the same with the above code. It's just the breakdown of how **piza.pname** and **pizas[index].pname** work in the same way.

**Newly Added**

If you want to display the result from **chicken pizza --> one --> later** to **chicken pizza --> later --> one**, you need to edit the List component:

```
<div 
   v-for="match in matchpizza" 
   :key="match.matchnum"
   :class="{ green: match.availability === 'buy now',
             red: match.availability === 'later',
           }"
>
    <div class="next-data-two">{{ match.availability }}</div> <!-- this is on the top now -->
    <div v-for="quantity in quantitys" :key="quantity.qname">
        {{ quantity.qname }}
    </div> <!-- this is on the bottom now -->
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the logic provided, But it is giving wrong path result, According to my output from codesandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/data-display-tcr8oj?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

For chicken pizza it showing as , chicken pizza --> one --> later...  But correct path is, chicken pizza --> later --> five... similarly for others also showing wrong path

Comment: I'm still a bit confused with the variable quantities in HelloWorld.vue. You already have qname in the variable matchpizza. What is the variable "quantities" for if I may ask? If you only want to change the position between the quantity and the availability. You need to change the position in the List component. Here is the codepen: https://codesandbox.io/s/data-display-forked-frxc50?file=/src/components/List.vue . Let me know if this is what you expect.