# How to target array index position correctly in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**HelloWorld.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(piza, index) in pizas" :key="piza.pname">
      {{ piza.pname }}
      <List
        :content="matchpizza"
        :pname="piza.pname"
        :qname="quantitys[index] ? quantitys[index].qname : ''"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import List from "./List.vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    List,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pizas: [
        {
          pname: "chicken pizza",
        },
        {
          pname: "chicken pizza spl",
        },
        {
          pname: "mutton pizza",
        },
        {
          pname: "plain pizza",
        },
      ],

      quantitys: [
        {
          qname: "one",
        },
        {
          qname: "two",
        },
        {
          qname: "three",
        },
        {
          qname: "four",
        },
        {
          qname: "five",
        },
      ],

      matchpizza: [
        {
          matchnum: "1",
          availability: "later",
          pname: "plain pizza",
          qname: "five",
        },
        {
          matchnum: "2",
          availability: "buy now",
          pname: "chicken pizza",
          qname: "one",
        },
        {
          matchnum: "3",
          availability: "buy now",
          pname: "plain pizza",
          qname: "five",
        },
        {
          matchnum: "4",
          availability: "buy now",
          pname: "chicken pizza spl",
          qname: "five",
        },
        {
          matchnum: "5",
          availability: "later",
          pname: "mutton pizza",
          qname: "five",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

List.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="matchpizza.length > 0">
      <div
        v-for="match in matchpizza"
        :key="match.matchnum"
        :class="{
          green: match.availability === 'buy now',
          red: match.availability === 'later',
        }"
      >
        <div v-for="quantity in quantitys" :key="quantity.qname">
          {{ quantity.qname }}
        </div>
        <div class="next-data-two">{{ match.availability }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-else class="next-data"><p>No availability</p></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  props: {
    content: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
    pname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    qname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data: function () {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    quantitys() {
      return this.content.filter((a) => a.qname === this.qname);
    },
    matchpizza() {
      return this.content.filter((a) => a.pname === this.pname);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.next-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-top: -2%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  color: blue;
}
.next-data-two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-top: -1%;
  margin-right: 42%;
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
</style>
```

See my working code here:-

https://codesandbox.io/s/data-display-tcr8oj?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

From the **helloworld.vue**  you can see this line         **:qname="quantitys[index] ? quantitys[index].qname : ''"**

Where as per the above code, from the quantitys array. it is not pointing to the particular index value correctly?.

**According to my output from codesandbox:-**

For chicken pizza it showing as , **chicken pizza --> one --> later**
But correct path is, **chicken pizza --> later --> five**

Similarly for others too, having same issue....

Is it because of index position wrong or issue with logic??

Comment: why are you posting code snippets that don't run ... anyway, you asked this [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409764/issue-when-trying-to-pass-array-value-as-string-via-props-in-vuejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned your required pathe is **chicken pizza --> later --> five**.

This path doesnot have to do anything with the `quantitys` array. You could simply display the details using the `content` prop itself.

**Working Fiddle** https://codesandbox.io/s/data-display-forked-kjxuyv